# want to put \' in my json object

Tags: .net, json

I am having trouble using JObject.Parse(string) to get this result:

```
'apos\'trophe'
```

But...

```
"apos\'trophe"    turns into    'apos'trophe'
"apos\\\'trophe"  turns into    'apos\\\'trophe'
"apos\\'trophe"   turns into    'apos\\'trophe'
"apos/\'trophe"   turns into    'apos/'trophe'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"apos\\\'trophe" works for me.`

Comment: You're right.  After you said this I went back and it was actually another piece of code that was then filtering my \' to '.  Thanks!